# $\int f d\mu<\infty$ iff $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} \mu(\{x \in X : f(x) \geq 2^{-n}\})< \infty$.

Tags: measure-theory

I have to prove this, but I really don't have any idea of how to start, I don't know which result or technique I could use. I would appreciate any hint or idea to prove this. Thank you.

> Let $(X, M, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X \to [0, \infty)$ be bounded. Then $\int f d\mu<\infty$ iff $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} \mu(\{x \in X : f(x) \geq 2^{-n}\}) < \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first prove the statement assuming that $f:X\to[0,1]$. By definition, $\int f\,d\mu=\int_0^1\mu(\{x\in X:f(x)\ge t\})\,dt=:\int_0^1 g(t)\,dt$, treated as a Riemann integral. Note that $g(t)$ is a nonincreasing function of $t$ and $g(1)=0$. Thus by the comparison test, $g(2^{\lceil\log_2 t\rceil})\le g(t)\le g(2^{\lfloor\log_2 t\rfloor})$ implies

\begin{array}{rll}
\int_0^1 g(2^{\lceil\log_2 t\rceil})\,dt\le&\!\!\!\!\int_0^1 g(t)\,dt\!\!\!\!&\le\int_0^1 g(2^{\lfloor\log_2 t\rfloor})\,dt\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{2^{-n-1}}^{2^{-n}} g(2^{\lceil\log_2 t\rceil})\,dt=&&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{2^{-n-1}}^{2^{-n}} g(2^{\lfloor\log_2 t\rfloor})\,dt\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{2^{-n-1}}^{2^{-n}} g(2^{-n})\,dt=&&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{2^{-n-1}}^{2^{-n}} g(2^{-n-1})\,dt\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n-1}g(2^{-n})=&&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}g(2^{-n})\\
\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}g(2^{-n})=&&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}g(2^{-n})+g(1),
\end{array}

and since $g(1)=0$ this expression takes the form $\frac12b\le a\le b$. Thus, since each expression bounds the other, $a:=\int f\,d\mu$ is bounded iff $b:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}g(2^{-n})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}\mu(\{x\in X:f(x)\ge 2^{-n}\})$ is bounded.

Now, we want to generalize this to arbitrary bounded $f$. If $f:X\to[0,M]$ for some $M\ge1$, then $\int f\,d\mu=\int_0^M g(t)\,dt$, so if we assume $\int f\,d\mu$ is bounded, then so is $\int_0^1 g(t)\,dt$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}g(2^{-n})$, by the above. But then $g(1)\le g(2^{-1})\le2\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}g(2^{-n}),$ so $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}g(2^{-n})$ is also bounded.

Conversely, if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}g(2^{-n})$ is bounded, then so is $\int_0^1 g(t)\,dt$ and $g(1)$, and
$$\int_0^M g(t)\,dt=\int_0^1 g(t)\,dt+\int_1^M g(t)\,dt\le\int_0^1 g(t)\,dt+(M-1)g(1),$$

so $\int f\,d\mu$ is bounded.